# Why mesh network nodes do not connect to the internet?

Tags: networking, wifi, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have 3 raspberry Pi 3 connected to a mesh network with batman-adv, a raspberry has a WIFI dongle and is the gateway to the internet. The gateway configuration is: A file named ~/start-batman-adv with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo batctl if add wlan0
sudo ifconfig bat0 mtu 1468
sudo batctl gw_mode server
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan1 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o bat0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i bat0 -o wlan1 -j ACCEPT

sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo ifconfig bat0 up
```

I added the line `/home/pi/start-batman-adv.sh &` in the file /etc/rc.local

I added the file `/etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan0` with the following:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wireless-channel 4
    wireless-essid RASPBERRY-MALLA
    wireless-mode ad-hoc
```

I executed in terminal the following commands:

```
echo 'batman-adv' | sudo tee --append / etc / modules
echo 'denyinterfaces wlan0' | sudo tee --append /etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

And added to `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` the following:

```
network = {
    ssid = "name of the wifi network"
    scan_ssid = 1
    psk = "password"
}
```

In the other two raspberry I made the same configuration as with the gateway, with the exception of the file `~/start-batman-adv`, in those two files has the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo batctl if add wlan0
sudo ifconfig bat0 mtu 1468
sudo batctl gw_mode client
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo ifconfig bat0 up
```

Commands on the gateway:

[image: ifconfig]
[image: iwconfig]
[image: batctl gw_mode]
[image: batctl n]

Commands on the nodes:

[image: ifconfig]
[image: iwconfig]
[image: batctl wgl and batctl wg_mode]

I have internet on the gateway, but why don't I have internet on the nodes?

Comment: most likely pi acting as gateway is not configure to route traffic. can you edit your question with result of `ip r s` ?

Comment: not just that: I can see nodes have an 169.254.x.y/16 address: this is supposed to be non-routable, but anyway, they also probably don't have a default route. A DHCP server would be needed on the gateway RPi or else the nodes need static IP network configuration.